# Android Studio i cant see "all Attributes"

Tags: android-studio

i start Android studio now and i was watching for "all Attributes"
but i cant see its empty

i try File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart.
and download Android Studio again
and i check SDK please help me
I also looked at the system environment variables.
T.T

[image]